# Auto-Updated Validated Cell When Source Value Changes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to update cells that have data validation restrictions on them automatically.
For example - Sheet1 has below column (Column E):

| Package Identifier |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

where the values are taken from the same named column (Column D) in Sheet2.
The below code works for MANUAL changes only

```
Sheet2 Code:

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim count_cells As Integer
Dim new_value As String
Dim old_value As String
Dim rng As Range
For count_cells = 1 To Range("D1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E3:E86")
    If Intersect(Target, Range("D" & count_cells + 1)) Is Nothing Then
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        new_value = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        old_value = Target.Value
        Target.Value = new_value
        rng.Replace What:=old_value, Replacement:=new_value, LookAt:=xlWhole
        Target.Select
    End If
Next count_cells
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So, if i manually change value B to Z, all the corresponding values that were B on Sheet1 now change to Z. The problem is, `Package Identifier` on Sheet2 is dictated by concatenating other columns

`=CONCATENATE(B35, "-", "Package", "-", TEXT(C35, "#000"))`

This piece of code breaks when trying to use it with the above formula. How can i make this set of code trigger on this formula based output?

Comment: I ended up getting confused as to what you are trying to achieve? Forget the code for a moment. Can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve? Possible to share screenshots of data from both sheets?

Comment: Run your Intersect check on columns B and C instead

Comment: @SiddharthRout i think i explained myself pretty clearly.

Sheet1 has column of data that is based on a list in on Sheet2 via data validation. When a value within the list on Sheet2 changes, say from A to Z, all the values that were selected as A should now change to Z.

This is the code above, the problem is the code above only works for MANUAL INPUTS. It wont work if the list value is based on a formula, because the formula recalculating is not a manual change.

See this example: https://excelenthusiasts.sharepoint.com/Documents/Automatic-validation-entry-changes%20v1.xlsm

Comment: @TimWilliams you are misunderstanding. The code above WORKS, but only for manual user input, not for input dictated by formulas changing. Changing the columns im referencing will do nothing useful.

Comment: `i think i explained myself pretty clearly.` Do you think it could be the coffee? Here is my understanding. Feel free to correct it. Col A in Source has a formula say in A2 which is `=CONCATENATE(B2, "-", "Package", "-", TEXT(C2, "#000"))`

The list in Sheet1 will show this value in the dropdown. Next user selects this value in Sheet1. Next user changes a value in say Col C of Source so, the DV list automatically gets updated but the value which was previously selected (reflecting in the cell) doesn't change. You want that value to reflect to the updated value. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: When an input to the formula in the DV list range changes, the result of the formula changes.  If you Undo the manual change to the formula input  you will then have both the “old” and “new” formula results to use in your replacement

Comment: Or instead capture the DV list selection event, and replace the selected value with a link to the corresponding cell in the DV list range.  Now your selections update when the source range updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is how the **Validation** sheet looks

[image]

and this is how the **Source** sheet looks

[image]

Let's say user selects first option in **Validation** sheet.

[image]

Now go back to **Source** sheet and change `1` to `2` in cell `C2`.

[image]

Notice what happens in **Validation** sheet

[image]

If this is what you are trying then based on the file that you gave, test this code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim NewSearchValue As String
    Dim OldSearchValue As String
    Dim NewArrayBC As Variant
    Dim OldArrayA As Variant, NewArrayA As Variant
    Dim lRow As Long, PrevRow As Long
    
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:C")) Is Nothing Then
        lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Store new values from Col A, B and C in an array
        NewArrayBC = Range("B1:C" & lRow).Value2
        NewArrayA = Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value2
        
        Application.Undo
        
        '~~> Get the old values from Col A
        OldArrayA = Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value2
        
        '~~> Paste the new values in Col B/C
        Range("B1").Resize(UBound(NewArrayBC), 2).Value = NewArrayBC
        
        '~~> Loop through the cells
        For Each aCell In Target.Cells
            '~~> Check if the prev change didn't happen in same row
            If PrevRow <> aCell.Row Then
                PrevRow = aCell.Row
            
                NewSearchValue = NewArrayA(aCell.Row, 1)
                OldSearchValue = OldArrayA(aCell.Row, 1)
    
                Worksheets("Validation").Columns(2).Replace What:=OldSearchValue, _
                Replacement:=NewSearchValue, Lookat:=xlWhole
            End If
        Next aCell
    End If
Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Comment: It won't work in a loop with multiple values changed in B,C. You would have to store all New values in A first and then call Undo only once.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach from Sid's...

Instead of updating values in the DV cells when the source range changes, this replaces the selected value with a link to the matching cell in the DV source range.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim rngV As Range, rng As Range, c As Range, rngList As Range
    Dim f As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    'any validation on this sheet?
    Set rngV = Me.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngV Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no DV cells...
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(rngV, Target)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no DV cells in Target
    
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then 'DV list?
            Set rngList = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            'see if we can get a source range
            Set rngList = Evaluate(c.Validation.Formula1)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rngList Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                'find cell to link to
                Set f = rngList.Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    c.Formula = "='" & f.Parent.Name & "'!" & f.Address(0, 0)
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print "No source range for " & c.Address
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```